# How to join two queries in access

Tags: sql, select, join, union

I am incapable of make a query that return me a results as follows:

TABLES: `series`, `usuarios`, `siguiendo`, `valoraciones_personales`

Each table has got this records:

example: `field1(value)`, `field2(value)`,...

`series` (I refer a tv show, I am spanish and here we say "serie=tv_show")

```
 1. id_serie(1),id_titulo('Sons of anarchy')
 2. id_serie(2),id_titulo('Lost')
```

`usuarios` (user)

```
 1. id_usuario(1), nick('david')
```

`siguiendo` (a usser follow a series)

```
 1. id_serie(1),id_usuario(1)
 2. id_serie(2),id_usuario(1)
```

`valoraciones_personales` (personal assessments)

```
 1. id_serie(1),id_usuario(1),nota(8)
```

Ok, what I want is a result with all records of the table siguiendo, and if that user valued one of that series, it must shows the score (nota in spanish), and if that user didn´t scored that series, I want to show "without score".

The view I want:

```
 *titulo, nota*

 - Sons of anarchy, 8 
 - Lost, without score
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: It may make easier reading if you renamed the tables in the question.  Maybe also layout the view you want as a table rather than a bullet list.  P.s. Take a look at left join and iif()

Comment: In MySQL, this works: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cd260/16/0

Answer (score 1):

Specifically in **MSACCESS**

Create a query called something like AllUserSeries

```
SELECT 
    U.UserID
    ,U.FullName
    ,S.SeriesID
    ,S.SeriesName
FROM 
   usuarios as U
   ,series  as S
```

This is the equivalent of a cross join

Then another:

```
SELECT
   A.FullName
   ,A.SeriesName
   ,Nz(Cstr(R.Score),"Not Rated") as Rating
FROM
   AllUserSeries AS A
   LEFT OUTER JOIN valoraciones_personales AS R
      ON A.UserID = R.UserID
      AND A.SeriesID = R.SeriesID
WHERE
   A.UserID = @UserID
```

The tricky bit is getting a list of all the series a user *may* have liked. to do this normally i would do a cross join to get all permutations that could exist, then left join from there to the ratings table using Nz to handle null values as you see fit.

*sorry for kinda making up the other column names it was easier for me to use English hope that okay :D

Comment: Watch out for multiple users rating a series - you may need to take a look at aggregates to average the score.